# How to set subl:// protocol handler with Unity?

Tags: 14.04, unity

My web app generates clickable URLs like the following when an error occurs:

```
subl://open?url=file://%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fwebenginex%2Fclass%2Fmodels%2Fwxclient.php&line=123
```

When I click it I get this prompt:

[image]

Clicking "Launch Application" does nothing. I want it to open Sublime Text as intended. How can I configure that?

Comment: Have a look a [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676981/sublime-text-url-handler-for-ubuntu) and just replace `txmt` with `subl` where needed.

Comment: @Bogdan Thanks, but when I run `sudo update-desktop-database` I get "Warning in file "/usr/share/applications/sublime-text-2.desktop": usage of MIME type "x-directory/normal" is discouraged ("x-directory" is an old media type that should be replaced with a modern equivalent)" and clicking a `subl://` link still gives this popup.

Comment: The warning shouldn't be an issue, it's only compaining about the use of a deprecated mime type and it's not in the `sublime-handler.desktop` file you should have created. The popup is to be expected because Chrome doesn't know how to handle special protocols like `subl`, so it asks if you want to use `xdg-open` (which is ok in this case). Just click on **Launch Application** and it should open the file in Sublime Text. Of course you can check the _Rememeber my choice for all links of this type_ so next time you won't be prompted.

Comment: @Bogdan Oh..I should have paid closer attention; I thought that *was* the file I created. I did try clicking Launch Application though, didn't do anything. Maybe I have to reboot...

Comment: It should't require a reboot. Try copying the `subl://` link from your browser and using it from the command line and see if it works `xdg-open subl://...`

Comment: I get "no matches found"

Comment: Can you update your question with the location and content of the files you created for this. I'd like to have a look, maybe you missed something. Also what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Bogdan 14.04. I was just updating the question like you asked when it started working. I didn't change anything since yesterday; could it be because I logged out and back in?

Comment: Maybe, I can't say for sure. I'm on 12.04 and for me it worked out of the box. At least the problem's solved :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## To register custom protocol handler in chrome

#### 1. Create the desktop file

Create the file `/usr/share/applications/sublime-handler.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime Text 2 URL Handler
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Handle URL Scheme subl://
Exec=/usr/share/handlers/sublime-handler %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/subl;
Icon=sublime-text-2
Categories=TextEditor;Development;Utility;
Name[en_US]=Sublime Text 2 URL Handler
```

#### 2. Update the MIME-types database

```
$ sudo update-desktop-database
```

#### 3. Create the handler file

Create the file `/usr/share/handlers/sublime-handler`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

request="${1#*://}"             # Remove schema from url (subl://)
request="${request#*?url=}"     # Remove open?url=
request="${request//%2F//}"     # Replace %2F with /
request="${request/&line=/:}"   # Replace &line= with :
request="${request/&column=/:}" # Replace &column= with :

subl "$request"                 # Launch sublime
```

Make it executable:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/share/handlers/sublime-handler
```

#### 4. Register mime-type handler

```
$ xdg-mime default /usr/share/applications/sublime-handler.desktop x-scheme-handler/subl
```

#### 5. Profit

Now you can open links with custom protocols from chrome via custom applications, example:

```
subl:///home/path/to/file.php:123
subl://open?url=/home/path/to/file.php:123
subl://open?url=/home/path/to/file.php&line=123
subl://open?url=/home/path/to/file.php&column=123
subl://open?url=%2Fhome%2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffile.php&line=123
subl://open?url=%2Fhome%2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffile.php&column=123
```

## 6. Modify

It can be ported for using with the different IDE, for example `phpstorm`

Comment: i used this technique to register a protocol for kate text editor like kate://  and it works perfect!

Comment: This works well also in Firefox!

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty much summarizing this and making it more copy-pastable...

Create the Sublime URL Parser file '/usr/local/bin/subl-url-parser':

```
sudo tee /usr/local/bin/subl-url-parser > /dev/null <<"EOF"
#!/usr/bin/env bash

request=${1:23}               # Delete the first 23 characters "subl://open?url=file://"
request=${request//%2F//}     # Replace %2F with /
request=${request/&line=/:}   # Replace &line= with :
request=${request/&column=/:} # Replace &column= with :
sublime $request              # Launch Sublime
EOF
```

Make it executable, and symlink it to "subl-url-handler":

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/subl-url-parser
sudo ln -s subl-url-parser /usr/local/bin/subl-url-handler
```

Create (or update) the desktop file ' /usr/share/applications/sublime-handler.desktop' to use your new URL parser via 'subl-url-handler':

```
sudo tee /usr/share/applications/sublime-handler.desktop > /dev/null <<EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime Text URL Handler
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Handle URL Scheme subl://
Exec=subl-url-handler %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/subl;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;Utility;
Name[en_US]=Sublime Text URL Handler
EOF
```

Update the databse:

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

---

**NB**: This assumes that you have a `sublime` in your `$PATH` and not just `subl`, as I do. If not, you can make one like this:

```
sudo ln -s `which subl` $(dirname `which subl`)/sublime
```

Comment: very cool. can be one script actually to run blindly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Sublime Text 3 (AKA ST3) and Andrey's answer above worked for me. I used a different dir for the handler, switched some "2"s for "3"s in labels, and I changed `request="${request#*?url=}"` to `request="${request#*?url=file://}"` but otherwise all the same.